# How do I pass a member function with object as an argument to pthread_create?

Tags: c++, pthreads

How do I pass member function with object as an argument to pthread_create function?

Example:

```
    class A
    {
       public:
         A(){}

         void funcForThread( Person p ) {
          //code...
         }

         void createThread( Person p ) {
            pthread_t thread1;
            pthread_attr_init ( &attr );
            pthread_attr_setdetachstate ( &attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE );
            pthread_create ( &thread1, &attr, /* what to write here*/ ); // need to pass funcForThread and Person p object there
         }

       private:
         pthread_attr_t attr;
    };
```

Comment: This isn't C, since C doesn't have classes or member functions.

Comment: You need to pass a proxy function.

Comment: @Barmar I do not know what the proxy function is could you please provide an example?

Comment: @stilltryingbutstillsofar See my answer!

Comment: With C++11, `std::thread` has better interface.

Comment: @Jarod42, it's also portable right?

Comment: yes, it is portable (and even more than `pthread` which has different signatures... if I remember correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Just like this

```
void *
call_member(void *data)
{
    A *a = reinterpret_cast<A *>(data);
    a->member();

    return NULL;
}
```

and then,

```
pthread_create(&thread1, &attr, call_member, this);
```